# botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetItem operation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, testing, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to reproduce, step-by-step, the instructions on this video **"Cloud Resume Challenge Sprint (Sept, 2022) - Week 4"** from youtube, https://youtu.be/wiyI0Ngn31o, on how to setup GitHub Actions with CD/CI pipeline for Backend testing with Python for SAM Deployment in AWS.

I have followed the video's instructions, step-by-step; however, when I push my mail.yml file to the GitHub repository, I get the following error message from GitHub Actions:

```
Run pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.15, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/runner/work/cloud-resume-challenge/cloud-resume-challenge
plugins: mock-3.10.0
collected 1 item

serverless-architecture-with-SAM/tests/test_handler.py F                 [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ test_lambda_handler ______________________________

    @mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"TABLENAME": TABLENAME})
    def test_lambda_handler():
        # Check AWS creds
        assert "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" in os.environ
        assert "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" in os.environ
    
>       ret = app.lambda_handler("", "")

serverless-architecture-with-SAM/tests/test_handler.py:20: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
serverless-architecture-with-SAM/hello_world/app.py:8: in lambda_handler
    response = table.get_item(
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py:580: in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py:88: in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:530: in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <botocore.client.DynamoDB object at 0x7f9b115349a0>
operation_name = 'GetItem'
api_params = {'Key': {'ID': 'visits'}, 'TableName': 'resume-website-app-tbl'}

    def _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params):
        operation_model = self._service_model.operation_model(operation_name)
        service_name = self._service_model.service_name
        history_recorder.record(
            'API_CALL',
            {
                'service': service_name,
                'operation': operation_name,
                'params': api_params,
            },
        )
        if operation_model.deprecated:
            logger.debug(
                'Warning: %s.%s() is deprecated', service_name, operation_name
            )
        request_context = {
            'client_region': self.meta.region_name,
            'client_config': self.meta.config,
            'has_streaming_input': operation_model.has_streaming_input,
            'auth_type': operation_model.auth_type,
        }
        endpoint_url, additional_headers = self._resolve_endpoint_ruleset(
            operation_model, api_params, request_context
        )
        request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
            api_params=api_params,
            operation_model=operation_model,
            endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
            context=request_context,
            headers=additional_headers,
        )
        resolve_checksum_context(request_dict, operation_model, api_params)
    
        service_id = self._service_model.service_id.hyphenize()
        handler, event_response = self.meta.events.emit_until_response(
            'before-call.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
                service_id=service_id, operation_name=operation_name
            ),
            model=operation_model,
            params=request_dict,
            request_signer=self._request_signer,
            context=request_context,
        )
    
        if event_response is not None:
            http, parsed_response = event_response
        else:
            apply_request_checksum(request_dict)
            http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                operation_model, request_dict, request_context
            )
    
        self.meta.events.emit(
            'after-call.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
                service_id=service_id, operation_name=operation_name
            ),
            http_response=http,
            parsed=parsed_response,
            model=operation_model,
            context=request_context,
        )
    
        if http.status_code >= 300:
            error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
            error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
>           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
E           botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetItem operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.15/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:960: ClientError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED serverless-architecture-with-SAM/tests/test_handler.py::test_lambda_handler - botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetItem operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
============================== 1 failed in 0.41s ===============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is a copy of my main.yml file:

```
name: main
on: push


jobs:
  test-infra:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 2
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          cd serverless-architecture-with-SAM/tests
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run tests with pytest
        env:
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
        run: pytest

  build-and-deploy-infra:
    needs: test-infra
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      - uses: aws-actions/setup-sam@v1
      - uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      - run: sam build
        working-directory: serverless-architecture-with-SAM
      - run: sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
        working-directory: serverless-architecture-with-SAM

  deploy-site:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
          args: --delete
        env:
          AWS_S3_BUCKET: justinhenson-cloud-resume-website
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          SOURCE_DIR: serverless-architecture-with-SAM/resume-site
```

Here is the file structure in my GitHub Repo: https://github.com/justin-henson/cloud-resume-challenge

```
account/cloud-resume-challenge
   .github/
       workflows/
           main.yml
   serverless-architecture-with-SAM/
       hello_world/
           __init__.py
           app.py
           requirements.txt
       resume-site/
           css/
           img/
           js/ 
           index.html
       Makefile
       tests/
               __init__.py
               requirements.txt
               test_handler.py
       README.md
       samconfig.toml
       template.yaml
   .gitignore
```

And the contents of my test_handler.py file:

```
import os
import re
import json

from unittest import mock

from hello_world import app

os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'

with open('serverless-architecture-with-SAM/template.yaml', 'r') as f:
    TABLENAME = re.search(r'TableName: (.*)?', f.read()).group(1)

@mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"TABLENAME": TABLENAME})
def test_lambda_handler():
    # Check AWS creds
    assert "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" in os.environ
    assert "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" in os.environ

    ret = app.lambda_handler("", "")

    # Assert return keys
    assert "statusCode" in ret
    assert "headers" in ret
    assert "body" in ret

    # Check for CORS in Headers
    assert "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  in ret["headers"]
    assert "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" in ret["headers"]
    assert "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" in ret["headers"]

    # Check status code
    if ret["statusCode"] == 200:
        assert "visit_count" in ret["body"]
        assert json.loads(ret["body"])["visit_count"].isnumeric()
    else:
        assert json.loads(ret["body"])["visit_count"] == -1

    return
```

And the contents of my app.py file:

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('resume-website-app-tbl')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = table.get_item(
        Key = {
            'ID':'visits'
        }
    )
    
    visit_count = response['Item']['counter'] 
    visit_count = str(int(visit_count) + 1)
    
    response = table.put_item(
        Item = {
            'ID':'visits',
            'counter': visit_count
        }
    )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
        },
        'body': visit_count
    }
```

Comment: your test python file is not getting aws creds properly.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my AWS credentials in GitHub Secrets, and this seems to have resolved my problem.